# Qt4: write QByteArray to file with filename?

Tags: c++, image, file, qt, arrays

I'm having trouble in Qt 4 with writing to non-text files. I have a QByteArray data and I want to save it to a file with name "some_name.ext" in specific directory: "C://MyDir". How can I do this? Note that the content is not textual.

The format is "GIF" and it is not supported by Qt.

```
QImage mainImage; 
if (!mainImage.loadFromData(aPhoto.data)) 
    return false; 
if (!mainImage.save(imageName, imageFormat.toUtf8().constData())) 
   return false;
```

I want to bypass somehow that restriction!

Comment: Why don't you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Here what I have to do. But save function returns false, because of the not supported format. So I think if I could save the byteArray data without passing through QImage, may be  I will succeed?!

Comment: Are you really really sure that you need the images in GIF format? Using other formats, for example PNG, makes life easier with Qt.

Comment: The GIF file format is considered obsolete nowadays. PNG is a better alternative.

Comment: Ok, do you know how to save it to other format? Yes, the other format is an option too. Thanks. (PNG, JPG... whatever)

Comment: Just give "PNG" as a format for the save() function. It doesn't matter what was the original format.

Comment: Thank you, **Roku**! It works, how I wanted!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To write a QByteArray to a file:

```
QByteArray data;

// If you know the size of the data in advance, you can pre-allocate
// the needed memory with reserve() in order to avoid re-allocations
// and copying of the data as you fill it.
data.reserve(data_size_in_bytes);

// ... fill the array with data ...

// Save the data to a file.
QFile file("C:/MyDir/some_name.ext");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
file.write(data);
file.close();
```

In Qt 5 (5.1 and up), you should use [QSaveFile](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsavefile.html) instead when saving a new complete file (as opposed to modifying data in an existing file). This avoids the situation where you lose the old file if the write operation fails:

```
// Save the data to a file.
QSaveFile file("C:/MyDir/some_name.ext");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
file.write(data);
// Calling commit() is mandatory, otherwise nothing will be written.
file.commit();
```

Remember to check for errors, of course.

Also note that even though this answers your question, it probably doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I wanted to do, but now I done with more tricky solution. I just wrote the QImage in different format, instead of do this.

Comment: Just a question... does this not leave open a possibility that write only writes part of the array before completing? In other words, should there not be a while loop here?

Comment: @LennartRolland Nope. The `write()` function will write out the entire array.

Comment: @NikosC. ok but what is the purpose of the "bytes written" return value?

Comment: @LennartRolland For normal files, the return value will be -1 if there's an error. For other `QIODevice` types  though, it might indicate that the device simply cannot hold all data, in which case `write()` would just return the amount of bytes that did fit, but there was no error. I'm not sure what happens if writing to a `QFile` results in all disk space running out. I think it would return -1 in that case. But either way, you wouldn't use a loop. You'd just call `write()` once and check if the return value is `< data.size()`, in which case you can treat that as an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use QDataStream to write binary data.

```
QFile file("outfile.dat");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QDataStream out(&file);
```

Then use

```
QDataStream & QDataStream::writeBytes ( const char * s, uint len )
```

or

```
int QDataStream::writeRawData ( const char * s, int len )
```

Comment: The problem is not writing binary files, it is writing images in GIF format.

Comment: I have readed a GIF Image and now the data is in QByteArray. Do you tell me that if I wrote the data to a file "blabla.gif" that will be useless (can I open it than with regular Image Viewer for gif files) ?

Comment: Yes, it will be useless. Image formats (like GIF, JPG, PNG) are used only during loading and saving. Internal representation is different. Just writing the internal representation to a file and giving the file name a .gif extension does not work.

Comment: So, then How to save this large sequence of '1' and '0' in the manner that the people can open it and view the beautiful landscape witch is encoded in QByteArray?

Comment: Have you done that "open it and view the beautiful landscape" part done yet? If so post the code.

Comment: Qt does support GIF images. Unless in the version of Qt you have installed the support has been disabled.

Comment: Do you know how to enable manually this support? I have looking at the open source, and I was thinking of adding the missing part if I found it somewhere somehow