# How to convert a TIF file into a BMP file in C++98 using QT 4?

Tags: c++, qt, bitmap, qt4, tiff

I am new in C++. How can I convert a TIF file into a BMP file in C++98?

Here is my "newForm.h".Here is private slots for loading tiff and coverting the image.

```
#ifndef _NEWFORM_H
#define _NEWFORM_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QDebug>

#include "ui_newForm.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class newForm; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class newForm : public QDialog {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    newForm();
    virtual ~newForm();

private slots:
    void on_load_tiff_PushButton_clicked();
    void on_bmp_PushButton_convert();

private:
    QString mResourceDir;
    Ui::newForm widget;
};

#endif /* _NEWFORM_H */
```

Here is my "main.cpp" in which i show the "newForm".

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "newForm.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // initialize resources, if needed
    // Q_INIT_RESOURCE(resfile);

    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    newForm a;
    a.show();
    
    // create and show your widgets here

    return app.exec();
}
```

Here is "newForm.cpp".Here is **on_load_tiff_PushButton_clicked** which load tiff image.I want to **convert tiff image into bitmap image** using **on_bitmap_PushButton_convert** .how i can do that

```
#include "newForm.h"
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QDebug>

newForm::newForm() {
    widget.setupUi(this);
    mResourceDir = "/root/NetBeansProjects/TIF_TO_BMP/file.tiff";
    
    connect(widget.pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_load_tiff_PushButton_clicked()));
    connect(widget.pushButton_2, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_bitmap_PushButton_convert()));
      
}
QString filename ;
void newForm::on_load_tiff_PushButton_clicked()
{
     filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Load Image"),mResourceDir,tr("Images (*.jpg *.tiff)"));
    if (filename.isEmpty()){
        return;
    }
    QPixmap p(filename);
    if (! widget.graphicsView->scene()){
        qDebug() << "No Scene!";
        QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
        widget.graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    }
    widget.graphicsView->scene()->addPixmap(p);
}
void newForm::on_bitmap_PushButton_convert()
{
    if (widget.graphicsView->scene()) {
        QPixmap p(filename);
        QByteArray bytes;
        QBuffer buffer(&bytes);
        buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        p.save(&buffer, "BMP"); // writes pixmap into bytes in PNG format
       // widget.graphicsView->scene()->clear();             
    }
}
newForm::~newForm() {
}
```

Here is image of the "newForm.ui"

[image]

I want this make "bmp" image on this directory **/root/NetBeansProjects/TIF_TO_BMP/file.tiff** in centos6.8 which is not made on clicking the **Convert_To_BMP** button that calls  **on_bitmap_PushButton_convert()**.

Comment: So what is wrong with the code that you wrote? Also since you appear to be on linux what bitmap format are you trying to write? Do you really want a Windows bitmap?

Comment: `connect(widget.pushButton_2, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_bitmap _clearPushButton_convert()));` there is a typo on this line. Not sure if this is your problem or if this is not the real code.

Comment: I want to convert **tiff** image into **bmp** onn clicking button "Convert_To_BMP" .Present code function **on_bitmap_PushButton_convert** is not creating **bmp** on this directory "/root/NetBeansProjects/TIF_TO_BMP/file.tiff" ?

Comment: @drescherjm, sorry it was typo on this line.I have edited .So please see the above explaination!! –

Comment: You probably need to use your debugger to verify that your conversion code is even being called. Also it may be a problem that you are specifying the exact same file name for the BMP and the tiff file instead of creating a different name for the bmp file. I don't think the conversion will change the extension for you.

Comment: I think I see the problem. The example code says ***This can, for example, be used to save an image directly into a QByteArray:*** Well a QByteArray is an object in c++ in memory and not a file on your disk. You would need to write the `QByteArray bytes;` to disk to save it as a file. See this answer on how to write a QByteArray to a file: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/12992140/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12992140/487892) ignore the `data.reserve(data_size_in_bytes);` line your `bytes` variable is already setup and ready to write to a file.

Comment: Try adding `QFile file("file.bmp");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
file.write(p);
file.close();` after `p.save(&buffer, "BMP");` and leave the rest of the code the same as  it is in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [stb](https://github.com/nothings/stb) which is a header-only library.

https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/tests/image_write_test.c

```cpp
   // make a RGB version of the template image
   // use red on blue to detect R<->B swaps
   unsigned char img6x5_rgb[6*5*3];
   float img6x5_rgbf[6*5*3];
   int i;

   for (i = 0; i < 6*5; i++) {
      int on = img6x5_template[i] == '*';
      img6x5_rgb[i*3 + 0] = on ? 255 : 0;
      img6x5_rgb[i*3 + 1] = 0;
      img6x5_rgb[i*3 + 2] = on ? 0 : 255;

      img6x5_rgbf[i*3 + 0] = on ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
      img6x5_rgbf[i*3 + 1] = 0.0f;
      img6x5_rgbf[i*3 + 2] = on ? 0.0f : 1.0f;
   }

   stbi_write_png("output/wr6x5_regular.png", 6, 5, 3, img6x5_rgb, 6*3);
   stbi_write_bmp("output/wr6x5_regular.bmp", 6, 5, 3, img6x5_rgb);
   stbi_write_tga("output/wr6x5_regular.tga", 6, 5, 3, img6x5_rgb);
   stbi_write_jpg("output/wr6x5_regular.jpg", 6, 5, 3, img6x5_rgb, 95);
   stbi_write_hdr("output/wr6x5_regular.hdr", 6, 5, 3, img6x5_rgbf);
```

Comment: Please, convert tiff to bmp without library ! Is it possible without library if any?

Comment: I think its very possible with the code you have already written in the question however if you can't debug / don't have a debugger I don't think you will get much help.

Comment: Qt supports image files formats via plugin https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qimage.html#reading-and-writing-image-files

Comment: @Henrique Bucher,Note: **p.save(&buffer, "BMP");**  buffer should save image **bmp** file in this **directory** **"/root/NetBeansProjects/TIF_TO_BMP/file.bmp"** but is not appearing there.In which **directory** of **centos 6.8** should it appear ?

Comment: My guess is the save failed because the file name you used was the same filename as you used for the tiff file and that tiff file already exists and is open. It does not append a .tiff to the end.

Comment: Use `QDir::currentPath()` to get the current path. OR store an absolute path in `filename`

Comment: It would try to write the file in whatever the current working directory was. That is the same for any `c++` program. When you don't specify a full path the file will be relative to the current working directory.

Comment: **qDebug() << QDir::currentPath()** is ginving me this dir **"/root/NetBeansProjects/TIF_TO_BMP/"**; It is not displaying **file.bmp** in this directory **"/root/NetBeansProjects/TIF_TO_BMP/"**

Comment: There is no place in your code that you set a file to file.bmp

Comment: @drescherjm, p.save(&buffer, "BMP"); -->here i set  file to file.bmp but no image appear at this directory **/root/NetBeansProjects/TIF_TO_BMP/**.How to convert **tiff** into **bmp** and make **bmp** at this directory ??